# Do I need to race through earlier difficulties to unlock everything in Mario Kart 7?

Tags: mario-kart-7

As a Mario Kart veteran, I have zero trouble getting through the 50cc and 100cc modes on my first try. However, it is somewhat time consuming to play through everything.

If I skip straight to 150cc, what will I be missing out on in terms of unlocks, awards, and the like?

Comment: I didn't find it particularly time-consuming. I got the best possible rating in every GP in 50cc first try. Personally I find it useful to start slower in order to learn the tracks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/997822-mario-kart-7/cheats), there are only two things you must play on lower ccs to get:

- The all-cast after-credits ending diorama, which requires gold for all cups on all ccs.
- A one-star, two-star, or three-star ranking, which requires said ranking or better for all cups on all ccs.

If you don't care about either of those, then go ahead and ignore the lower ccs. If you care about having a star ranking, then I suggest you do all the lower ccs first so you can finish them and never go back.